# pandas series inside pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have imported data from a database in my Jupyter notebook.

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('...')
cursor =cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("...")
tables = cursor.fetchall()
```

And then I convert `tables` into a `data frame`.

```
Db2Df = []

for row in tables:
    Db2Df.append({...,...})

df = pd.DataFrame(Db2Df)
df.head()
```

So after doing the above, I am exploring my data.

Input:

```
type(df)
type(df["Column_1"])
type(df["Column_1"][0])
```

Output:

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
pandas.core.series.Series
str
```

My question is, why is the data type like that (why does it do that)? A `str` inside a `pandas series` inside a `data frame`? And when working with the data, should I be considering using the `data frame` or `series`, if I want to manipulate the `str`...

Thank you.

Comment: `df` is a data frame, so is basically a big matrix with some rows and some columns. When you do `df['Column_1']` you are accessing the column named `Column_1`, which is a `Series`. So each column is a series, and a data frame has many columns

Comment: to expand on what @RafaelC said, when manipulating data in a dataframe, you will often iterate over a column, or group of columns. When you do this it is important to know the type of data you are working with so you know which operations can be performed on the data.

Comment: You will **not** be *often* iterating over a column actually

Answer (score 0):

Think of a dataframe as a dictionary of series:

```
d = dict(col1=['a', 'b', 'c'], col2=['d', 'e', 'f']
```

is quite similar to pd.DataFrame.

In fact you can convert this dictionary `d` to dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

After creating it your types as just the way you describe them, this is quite expected behviour:

```
assert isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)
assert isinstance(df.col1, pd.Series)
assert isinstance(df.col1[0], str)
```